# expected value of mixed RV

Tags: probability, random-variables, lebesgue-integral, expected-value

I am trying to find a formula to find the expected value of a RV that is mixed (continuous and discrete).

I defined the nonnegative RV $Y$ as a function of the absolutely continuous RV $X$.
$Y=X$ if $X$ takes Values in $[a,b]$ and $Y=C$ else, while $C$ is a discrete RV.

if $\mathbb{I}$ denotes the indicator function i can write:

$Y=\mathbb{I}_{[a,b]}(X)X+\mathbb{I}_{[0,a)\cup(b,\infty)}(X)C$ (is this right?)

with the definition of the expected Value from measure theory i wrote (if it exists):

$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[g(X)]=\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{I}_{[a,b]}(X)X+\mathbb{I}_{[0,a)\cup(b,\infty)}(X)Cd\mathbb{P}=\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{I}_{[a,b]}(X)Xd\mathbb{P}+\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{I}_{[0,a)\cup(b,\infty)}(X)Cd\mathbb{P}$.

I think the first Integral can be solved like this:
$X:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined on the measure space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{A}_1,\mathbb{P})$.

define the pushforward measure $P_X(A):=\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(A))$ and $Z:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $Z(x)=x$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{A}_2,P_X)$.

By using the change of variable theorem:

$\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{I}_{[a,b]}(X)Xd\mathbb{P}=\int_{[a,b]}Z(X(x))dP_X(x)=\int_{[a,b]}xdP_X=\int_{[a,b]}xf_X(x)dx$

when $f_X$ denotes the density of $X$.

I had trouble finding the second integral:
$\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{I}_{[a,0)\cup(b,\infty)}(X)Cd\mathbb{P}$.

I know that i can write $C$ as a simple function, what makes it easy to integrate it. But i dont know how to deal with the indicator function.

I think the Integral should be something like:

$\mathbb{P}(X\in[0,a)\cup(b,\infty))\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}c_i\mathbb{P}(C=c_i)$ when $c_i$ is the realisation of $C$.

I would appreciate any help or tips.
Im sorry if anything ist unclear formulated since english is not my First language and i am very new to measure theory.

Comment: Please provide additional details about the question like the specific probability distribution you have in mind, what are $a, C$ and $D$, and also your attempts to solve the problem. You are more likely to get support from the community if the question is well specified.

Comment: thank you im gonna edit my question!

Comment: The precise relationships between $Y, C, D$ are not clear. Assuming that $Y$ is a nonnegative random variable, you can indeed use $E[Y] = \int_0^{\infty} P[Y>t]dt$.

Comment: im sorry for the confusion. $Y$ is a nonengative RV and a function of $C$. $Y=C$ if $C\in I$ and $Y=D$ else.

Comment: I inserted my Probabilities and tried to use indicator function to have better boerders to integrate but could not find anything that seemed helpful until now. I would appreciate if you have any knowledge about how to calculate the Integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use joint pdf $P(C=c,X=x) = P(C=c) P(X=x)$.

$$E(g(X,C)) = \int \sum_c \ g(x,c) \times P(C=c,X=x) \ \  dx$$
$$E(1_S(X) C) = \int \sum_c \ 1_S(x) \times  c \times P(C=c,X=x) \ \  dx$$
$$E(1_S(X) C) = \int \sum_c  1_S(x) \times c \times P(C=c) P(X=x)\ \  dx$$
$$E(1_S(X) C) = \sum_c c P(C=c)  \int 1_S(x) P(X=x) \ \ dx $$
$$E(1_S(X) C) = P(X \in S) \times \sum_c c P(C=c)$$
$$E(1_S(X) C) = P(X \in S) \times E(C)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! How do i know that $X$ and $C$ are independent (is this the reason i can say $\mathbb{P}(X=x,C=c)=\mathbb{P}(X=x)\mathbb{P}(C=c)$ ?). How do i get to use the formula you used to calculate the expected value of $g(X,C)$- because i only knew that you can use this formula, if my varibles have a density function (but $C$ is discrete).  would it also be possible to say $\mathbb{E}[g(X,C)]=\int_{\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}}g(x,c)d\mathbb{P}(x,c)$? because i would like to start from the definition from measure theory.

Comment: You are correct. Only when $X,C$ are independent you can use the formula $P(X=x,C=c) = P(X=x) P(C=c)$ and if density function does not exist as you pointed out, you have to use the formula $E(g(X,C)) = \int g(x,c) dP(x,c)$. where $P(x,c)$ is the measure in the product space (product of space of $X$ and $C$).

Comment: Thank you! your reply really helped me to solve my problem.

Comment: If you are convinced then accept the answer by clicking on the side of my answer.